# How can I pass a function name to a test runner?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I wanted to write my own test runner:

```
do_test () {
  function_under_test=$1
  expected="$2"
  function_under_test $3  # <-- Line 32
  if [ $result -eq $expected ]; then
    printf '.'
  else
    printf 'F'
  fi
}
```

so that I can call it with

```
do_test sum_squares 385 10
```

and it would then use

```
sum_squares () {
  result=0
  num_in=$1
  for each_num in `seq $num_in`
  do
    result=$((result+(each_num*each_num)))
  done
}
```

but I'm getting `function_under_test: not found` at line 32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `function_under_test`, the shell think it's a command, not a variable. You need to expand it, so `function_uneder_test` will be expanded to `sum_squares`.

Change your line 32 to:

```
"$function_under_test" "$3"
```